# Is it possible to static analyze gradle scripts in sonarqube?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I’m currently trying to analyze gradle through sonarqube.
Is it possible to static analyze gradle scripts with sonarqube?
It if possible, do you have any references I can refer to?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube only supports languages: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/overview/

SonarQube does not support [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)s which a Gradle build file is written in (Groovy DSL/Kotlin DSL).

However, if you create a [custom Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html#java_gradle_plugin) that is written in either Java or Kotlin (SonarQube does not support Groovy as of 2021-01-12) then you can have it analyzed with SonarQube as with any other project.